# Java High Level Rest Client Memory Usage In Range Queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-7

Following function run range queries on the elastic search, when I use this function repeatedly in a multithread environment, The memory increases drastically until the application crashes.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

```
/**
  RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient( //
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost",9200,"http")));
**/
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllDocumentsInRange(long startTime, long endTime,
       RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
    try {
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders//
                .rangeQuery("date")//
                .gte(startTime)//
                .lte(endTime);


        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

        searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);

        searchSourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("date").order(SortOrder.ASC));

        searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);

        searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        List<Map<String, Object>> docsMap = new ArrayList<>();

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(new String[] { "mainIndex" }, searchSourceBuilder);

        Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(30));
        searchRequest.scroll(scroll);


        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient( //
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost",9200,"http")));

        SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

        while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) {

            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
                Map<String, Object> elasticDocVersion = hit.getSourceAsMap();
                docsMap.add(elasticDocVersion);
            }

            SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);
            scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);

            searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

            searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        }

        ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
        clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
        ClearScrollResponse clearScrollResponse = //
                restHighLevelClient.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        boolean succeeded = clearScrollResponse.isSucceeded();
        logger.trace("search scroll clearation:{}", succeeded);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("error in creaing QueryBuilder class: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

this is my memory usage image after running the application

[image: memory usage image]

I have tried different solutions, like synchronize the above function but none of them solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what elasticsearch client version you are using, but you may be interested in [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33342) elasticsearch rest client memory leak.

Also, I'm not sure which one is intended the `restHighLevelClient` that is passed in or the one that is created in the method. Only one is valid, but in any case, I would suggest calling `restHighLevelClient.close()` or using it in a try-with-resources when done with the client.

```
try (RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = 
   new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost",9200,"http"))) {
...
}
```